# AWS Cognito - run another lambda after migration lambda has run

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Cognito has a migration lambda that allows us to confirm a user in our db. They send the email and PW to Cognito, the lambda fires, we verify matches, and the user is entered into Cognito.

At this point - behind the scenes - Cognito generates a username of some kind (UUID). The problem is, I need a way to get this username into our existing database, because our systems going forward will no longer rely on email and instead rely on this username.

Ideal flow:

- Sign In
- Migration Succeeds
- Cognito generates username
- Username is sent to our server.

Now because we have email set to auto-verified, no post-confirmation lambda can be called. The only way I see to do this with Cognito as-is is to either:

1. Ask users who already exist in our system to confirm their email again. This is a non-starter
2. Create a post-auth lambda, check user login count through a custom attribute, and if 0 (or if not already registered with the service, etc.) migrate the username to the new service.

If there is *any* other way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

After the user migration lambda is called your pre sign-up lambda will be called, assuming you have implemented it. The parameters received by your lambda will include username with the value being the UID you referenced. Parameters will also include user attributes containing email. You can use this information to update your database.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to add the PreSignup trigger, its a complicated way of doing it if you already rely on PostConfirmation, and if the majority of new users won't be migrations. My use case has a frontend initiate the signup process as well, which I use here.

Instead, I set a Cognito attribute on the new user during the UserMigration trigger. It could be `'user_migration': <oldUserSub>`, or however you want to mark it. Just make sure you allow this property within the Cognito user pool settings.

When the UserMigration trigger returns, this information is now accessible through verifying the IdToken, or found in the JWT on the frontend if you're using that. So, when the user is migrated into Cognito and the response gets back to the Cognito client on the frontend, I can now recognize this user needs to be migrated into my personal database. Seeing this, I'll call a new endpoint on my backend to handle this. This new endpoint does exactly what PostConfirmation would typically do.

Then just delete the 'user_migration' property from the Cognito user, return the new user data to the frontend and everything should be set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pre sign-up** trigger. In order to detect if the trigger event came from your migration trigger, you can check at the `trigger_source` value from the `event` object. In my case (i'm using migration trigger) the value is `PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser`. By knowing the value of `trigger_source` you can differentiate if it was migrated or regular user. You can also check the user attributes to know whether the email or phone is verified or not.

Here's my sample code on python:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    trigger_source = event.get('triggerSource')
    user_attributes = request.get('userAttributes')
    email_verified = user_attributes.get('email_verified')
    
    if trigger_source == 'PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser' and email_verified == 'true':
        # create user on db
```